# Mediawiki patch to 1.23.14 breaks StripMath (MathJax?)

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

I just applied patch 1.23.14 to a 1.23.13 installation.

Now none of the pages with `<math>` work -- they all return

```
Fatal exception of type MWException
```

Note that I already have the following in LocalSettings.php:

```
require_once( "$IP/extensions/MathJax/MathJax.php" );
# Hack to get MathJax working per https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension_talk:MathJax#.5BWORKAROUND.5D_MathJax_works_in_preview.2C_but_not_in_page_display
$wgParserCacheType = CACHE_NONE;
```

With `$wgShowExceptionDetails = true;` I get the following detail:

```
[8949f7d9] /index.php?title=Precision_Models Exception from line 77 of /includes/parser/StripState.php: Invalid marker: '"`UNIQed9bcc3cd22378bd-MathJax-12-QINU

Backtrace:

#0 /includes/parser/StripState.php(58): StripState->addItem(string, string, string)
#1 /extensions/MathJax/MathJax.php(360): StripState->addNoWiki(string, string)
#2 [internal function]: MathJax_Parser::StripMath(array)
#3 /extensions/MathJax/MathJax.php(291): preg_replace_callback(string, string, string)
#4 [internal function]: MathJax_Parser::Stage2(Parser, string, StripState)
#5 /includes/Hooks.php(204): call_user_func_array(string, array)
#6 /includes/GlobalFunctions.php(4068): Hooks::run(string, array, NULL)
#7 /includes/parser/Parser.php(1222): wfRunHooks(string, array)
#8 /includes/parser/Parser.php(396): Parser->internalParse(string)
#9 /includes/content/WikitextContent.php(322): Parser->parse(string, Title, ParserOptions, boolean, boolean, integer)
#10 /includes/WikiPage.php(3614): WikitextContent->getParserOutput(Title, integer, ParserOptions)
#11 /includes/poolcounter/PoolCounterWork.php(112): PoolWorkArticleView->doWork()
#12 /includes/Article.php(710): PoolCounterWork->execute()
#13 /includes/actions/ViewAction.php(44): Article->view()
#14 /includes/Wiki.php(487): ViewAction->show()
#15 /includes/Wiki.php(285): MediaWiki->performAction(Article, Title)
#16 /includes/Wiki.php(647): MediaWiki->performRequest()
#17 /includes/Wiki.php(506): MediaWiki->main()
#18 /index.php(46): MediaWiki->run()
#19 {main}
```

Any tips on fixing or debugging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I'm not sure how this was working in previous versions.

The current [version 1.0 of the MathJax MediaWiki extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:MathJax) requires [a full local install of MathJax](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/start.html#installing-your-own-copy-of-mathjax).

One can verify the MathJax install itself by getting `baseURL/MathJax/test`.

Then the extension requires fully implementing [the extension's installation instructions](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:MathJax#Installation), which are more substantial than before.